# PyMySQL will not install onto raspberry pi

Tags: python, mysql, raspberry-pi

I have tried every answer I can find to install PyMySQL for example see below:

```
sudo pip install PyMySQL
Downloading/unpacking PyMySQL
Downloading PyMySQL-0.7.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl (78kB): 78kB downloaded
Installing collected packages: PyMySQL
Successfully installed PyMySQL
```

But still no luck, it just returns the following when .py script is run which uses pymysql:

```
python UpworkCode.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "UpworkCode.py", line 2, in <module>
import PyMySQL
ImportError: No module named PyMySQL
```

Please could someone help me out of this pit of despair thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `import pymysql` instead!In fact, the correct package name is `pymysql`, not `PyMYSQL`!
Remember,pip is not case sensitive, but python is!